# Saving and Retrieving UILabel value with NSUserDefaults

Tags: iphone, save, uilabel, nsuserdefaults

I trying to save `UILabel` value to `NSUserDefaults`. I did `IBAction` with this code:

```
-(IBAction)saveData:(id)sender {
    NSString *resultString = label.text;
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [prefs setObject:resultString forKey:@"result"];
    [prefs synchronize];

}
```

Then, I connect it to button with `Touch Up Inside`.
What log shows after I pressed the button:

```
result = 0;
```

When I pressed a second time, then it works.

```
result = "28.34";
```

**What I'm doing wrong and how can I retrieve a result?**

**EDIT**

With this code I display result in log. I put it to same action.

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation]);
```

Comment: Where is your log statement? Please provide that part of the code.

Comment: Where and how are you displaying the result?

Comment: you posted code for setting userdefault similarly post where you are using nsuserdefault to print value of result

Comment: I don't know how to display the result from NSUserDefaults. Look at edited code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct, so the issue is probably not the function you posted but rather the code that contains your `NSLog`. You might be logging the value in a way that misses the first time it gets set.

Answer (score 0):

Your log statement should be

> NSLog(@"%@",[[NSUserDefaults
>   standardUserDefaults]
>   objectForKey:@"result"]);

This should be after you set the object in NSUserDefaults.

Comment: Still display correct result after second press. Can you help me with retrieving result from NSUserDefaults? I don't know what code and where i put it.

Comment: You are saving your label value in NSUserDefaults using the key "result". To get back its value from NSUserDefaults, you need to write [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"result"]. But before getting the value, I hope the value is set. You are setting the value on clicking of the button. Hence, when you click the button for the first time, your value would not have been set in NSUserDefaults is my guess. Is your log statement inside your saveData?

Comment: Where I need to put the code to retrieve the value? In MyAppDelegate.m? Yes, Log statement is inside saveData.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your applicationDidFinishLaunching in appDelegate or in init method in viewController(you have to create one) :

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];   
if(prefs == nil)  
{      
[prefs setObject:@"anything" forKey:@"result"];  
    [prefs synchronize];  
}
```